# Need help using jquery Accordion on quadruple nested tables

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm a complete web languages noob, so forgive me if I can't explain this well, or if it's something extremely easy.  As a side task right now, my manager wished to turn a list(extremely similar to reddit sidebars) into a collapsible set by any means necessary to clear up some clutter.  The Layout is always:

> Head
>
> content
>
> Head
>
> content

[Here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-accordion-tutorial/) is the source of what I'm using.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QtNbC/3/) is a (probably incorrectly done) jsfiddle of what I'm trying trying to accordion.  Note that it should be row by row, but again, complete noob at the stuff, etc etc.
HTML:

```
<div>
        <tr class="head">
              <td colspan="2" valign="top"><span class="style106">head1</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="content">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td valign="top"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">content1</a></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div>
        <tr class="head">
          <td colspan="2" valign="top"><span class="style106">head2</span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="content">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="top"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">content2</a></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.head').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.head').parent('div').find('.content').not(':animated').fadeToggle(500);
   });
});
```

Comment: Just a quick question, do you really have `<tr>`s that are not inside of a `<table>` ?
incase you're unaware: `<table><tr><td></td>(*n)</tr>(*n)</table>` is how a table should be written, arguably with `<thead>` and `<tbody>` in their appropriate places :)

One problem you will quickly run in to (and I have before) is that `<table>` inners are __NOT__ block level elements, so block-style animation will not work correctly (or at all) on them

Comment: It's a really bad case of lots of tables, so they're nested 4 levels deep where they're at.  We're talking a 2006 website that's entirely tables and cleverly placed margins and paddings.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solution work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/QtNbC/4/

```
<div id="collapseMenu">

  <div class="head"><span class="style106">head1</span></div>
  <div class="content"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">content1</a></div>

  <div class="head"><span class="style106">head2</span></div>
  <div class="content"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">content2</a></div>

</div>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $contents = $("#collapseMenu .content").hide();
  var $heads = $("#collapseMenu .head").on( "click" , function(e) {

    var $next = $(this).next( $contents );
    $contents.not( $next ).slideUp();
    $next.slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();

  });

});
```

the theory here is:

We create a `collapseMenu` wrapper that we then put all of our `head`s and `content`s in pairs. Each time we `click` on a `head` we tell jQuery to find the `next()` `content` and then `slideToggle()` it. we also tell jQuery to `slideUp()` all the `content`s so that none are open simultaneously. (this can be disabled if you wish).

Comment: Didn't work out, so I jsfiddle'd the whole darned table in all of its horrible glory.  Although it's nested many layers deep in a table and isn't wrapped by a table tag in this particular segment, I went ahead and did that because I figured it was required.  [Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/QtNbC/5/)

Comment: Yeh , I thought that but noticed you only had a small amount of HTML in the fiddle so hoped u were able to edit the HTML ;) unfortunately unless you want some problems you cannot put anything inside of a table other than `<tr><td><th>` ... it'd be better if you paste the real source with no edits, then I'll try to help you. Heads up though: You wont be able to do nice animations on a table :(